# Use two components from different layouts

Tags: eclipse, android-layout, android

I have 2 layouts,in first layout I have EditText,Button and in second layout I have TextView. What I want is when i write something in EditText to copy that in second layout when you press button,but i get crash every time. Is there any way to use components from two layouts or i am missing something. If this is imposible another way would be good. Thx

main activity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle ivansad) {
            super.onCreate(ivansad);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Button Start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStart);
            Start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    setContentView(R.layout.numbers);
                    Intent Changeto2 = new Intent (MainAct.this, Numgen.class);
                    startActivity(Changeto2);
                }
            }); 
        }
```

second activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.numbers);
    Button Next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bNext);
    final EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.broj1);
    final TextView edit = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lb1);
    Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    edit.setText(text.getText());
        }
    });

}
```

First layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:ignore="Deprecated"
android:background="@drawable/grey_bg" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bNext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_x="-1dp"
    android:layout_y="405dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:text="Dalje"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
<EditText
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:id="@+id/broj1"
    android:layout_width="154dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_x="164dp"
    android:layout_y="6dp"
    android:background="@drawable/text_bg"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="1-49"
    android:inputType="number"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" >
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Second Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/grey_bg"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
android:id="@+id/lb1"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_x="80dp"
android:layout_y="107dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="  "
android:textSize="18sp"
tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: I encourage you to learn more about object oriented programming. Start some of the beginner android tutorials, learn how to pass data values through classes etc.

Comment: If you could provide more information that would be great.  Possibly a stack trace, or some actual code snippets.  Details would be appreciated as well (ex. Are you inflating a layout that contains the two child layouts?)  As of right now, it's not possible to help you given the amount of info provided.

Comment: I am but i want to do something myself its not interesting if you are just following someones instructions

Comment: what do you mean with "different layouts"? Add some code where we can see actually what you are trying to do

Comment: by different layouts i mean if you set one layout for activity can you use buttons from another layout in that activity

Comment: To answer your question, yes, it is possible. Since you don't want anyone to tell you how to actually do it there's not much else to say.

Comment: OK can you tell how to do it please

Comment: you are trying to access some `Views` which are a part of a different layout. As far as I understood, u are trying to pass some text between `Activities`?

Comment: yeah that is right,any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is have two separate activities, one to edit the text, and one to display it.

The first one you want to set the layout to layout_main, and set a callback for the button. Inside the callback you want:

```
final EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.broj1);
Intent intent = new Intent(MainAct.this, NumGen.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("mString",text.getText().toString());
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then inside your second activity (NumGen?) you can get that string you saved by doing this:

```
Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
String mString="";
if(data.containsKey("mString")){ mString=data.getString("mString"); }
```

One of the main issues it looks like you might be having is the ids defined in your XML files aren't the same as the ids in your code. After that, read up on how Activities work and pass information.